# split a data.frame using intervals

Tags: r, dataframe

This question is quite similar to this post [Splitting a data frame into a list using intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137490/splitting-a-data-frame-into-a-list-using-intervals), but the answer doesn't apply to my data because I don't have a column with binary values.

My data looks like this:

```
>df
    V1       V2       V3         V4 V5     V6       V7       V8    V9 V10 V11
1 chr1 49828662 49828663  rs7531656  0 +|chr1 48998526 50489626 AGBL4   1   -
2 chr1 62594676 62594677  rs2481665  0 +|chr1 62208148 62629591  PATJ   1   +
3 chr1 62633580 62633581  rs2457831  0 +|chr1 62208148 62629591  PATJ   1   +
4 chr1 66379767 66379768 rs12757124  0 +|chr1 66378927 66840262 PDE4B   1   +
5 chr1 66392060 66392061 rs55824844  0 +|chr1 66378927 66840262 PDE4B   1   +
6 chr1 66393984 66393985 rs35185259  0 +|chr1 66378927 66840262 PDE4B   1   +
```

What I need is split the file based on the column `V2` and in an interval of `5e+05`, the output will be something like this

```
[[1]]
1 chr1 49828662 49828663  rs7531656  0 +|chr1 48998526 50489626 AGBL4   1   -

[[2]]
2 chr1 62594676 62594677  rs2481665  0 +|chr1 62208148 62629591  PATJ   1   +
3 chr1 62633580 62633581  rs2457831  0 +|chr1 62208148 62629591  PATJ   1   +

[[3]]
4 chr1 66379767 66379768 rs12757124  0 +|chr1 66378927 66840262 PDE4B   1   +
5 chr1 66392060 66392061 rs55824844  0 +|chr1 66378927 66840262 PDE4B   1   +
6 chr1 66393984 66393985 rs35185259  0 +|chr1 66378927 66840262 PDE4B   1   +
```

My data has ~5millions rows, so the speed would be an issue but I can deal with it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this instead:

```
split(df, cumsum(c(F, diff(df$V2) > 5e5)))

$`0`
    V1       V2       V3        V4 V5     V6       V7       V8    V9 V10 V11
1 chr1 49828662 49828663 rs7531656  0 +|chr1 48998526 50489626 AGBL4   1   -

$`1`
    V1       V2       V3        V4 V5     V6       V7       V8   V9 V10 V11
2 chr1 62594676 62594677 rs2481665  0 +|chr1 62208148 62629591 PATJ   1   +
3 chr1 62633580 62633581 rs2457831  0 +|chr1 62208148 62629591 PATJ   1   +

$`2`
    V1       V2       V3         V4 V5     V6       V7       V8    V9 V10 V11
4 chr1 66379767 66379768 rs12757124  0 +|chr1 66378927 66840262 PDE4B   1   +
5 chr1 66392060 66392061 rs55824844  0 +|chr1 66378927 66840262 PDE4B   1   +
6 chr1 66393984 66393985 rs35185259  0 +|chr1 66378927 66840262 PDE4B   1   +
```

Comment: I getting some errors @Psidom with another data.table, could you help me?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the problem you have or post as another question if comment is not enough for you to describe. Either I or other people will be glad to help.

Comment: No worries @Psidom, the problem was when the difference was negative, but I realise that with `split(df, cumsum(c(F, abs(diff(df$V2)) > 5e5)))` the problem is solved

Comment: Presort the data frame by the column V2 is also a possible solution.

Comment: yep, you are right, what I don't understand properly is `F` in your solution, does indicate a function? I have tried replacing `F` with another letter but obviously I get an error telling me that the object doesn't exit. Could you please explain what `F` means in your solution?

Comment: F is the logical constant FALSE. Sorry I didn't make that clear. It is a way to keep the resulting vector the same length as the number of rows of your original data frame while maintaining the logic be correct, since diff function will reduce the length by one.

Answer (score 3):

First make your split points:

`splits <- seq(0,5e6, 5e5)`

Here's some dummy data that could be in your V2 column:

`v2 <- runif(5e6, 0, 5e6)`

Now call cut on this column to create a factor using the split points:

```
f <- cut(v2, splits)
> table(f)
f (0,5e+05] (5e+05,1e+06] (1e+06,1.5e+06] (1.5e+06,2e+06] (2e+06,2.5e+06] (2.5e+06,3e+06] (3e+06,3.5e+06] (3.5e+06,4e+06] (4e+06,4.5e+06] (4.5e+06,5e+06]

     499497        500111          499327          501262          499155          500263          500484          499776          500899          499226
```

Finally call split on your `data.frame` and pass the factor:

`df.list <- split(mydf, f)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting the same output as @Zelazny7. Here is my method with a `data.table` called `mydat`.

```
library(data.table)

breaks = 5e+05*(floor(min(mydat$V2)/5e+05):ceiling(max(mydat$V2)/5e+05))
mydat$X<-mydat[,.(X = cut(V2, breaks = breaks))]
mylist<-split(mydat, mydat$X)
```

Comment: I had a typo in my `seq` function

Comment: Yeah I figured that. It worked well once I fixed it.